# How do I combine my two strings to add it on to the previous string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, user-interface

This inherited and overridden method from BankAccount’s abstract version returns a String report. Because CheckingAccount is a sub class of BankAccount, this is a requirement. This method returns the following.
A local String variable for report is initialized to “Ch#:” + accountNumber + “ WDs(“ + numOfWithdraws + ”)” + “ Dep(“ + numOfDeposits + ”)” + “ PreBal: “ + moneyString(balance).

Next the hasOverdraft( ) method is called in an if statement to determine the status of the account (if the account hasOverdraft).  If true, then concatenate a tabbed “YrlyIntRate: “ to the yearlyInterestRate.  Next concatenate a tabbed “NewBal: “ to moneyString(balance) and concatenate “ (OD)” to indicate that the account is overdrafted.

Else if the balance is less than 100 (this is strictly for formatting the text area), then calculate the new balance by using the monthly interest rate and concatenate to the report String double-tabbed “YrlyIntRate: “ with the yearlyInterstRate and then concatenate the single tabbed “NewBal: “ with the moneyString(balance)

Otherwise do the above with a single tabbed YrlyIntRate (so all lines up nice).

```
public String bankAccountStatusReport()
{
    String r = "Ch#:" + accountNumber + " WDs("+ numOfWithdraws + ")"+
        " Dep("+ numOfDeposits +")" + " PreBal:"+ moneyString(balance);

    hasOverdraft();
    if(hasOverdraft()== true)
    {
        String r += "\t" + "YrlyIntRate:" + yearlyInterestRate 
                + "\t" + " NewBal:" + moneyString(balance) + " (OD)"; ;
    }
    else if(balance < 100)
    {

    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: This reads like a homework assignment. What is *your* question?

Comment: I agree with @cricket_007. A much better question would tell us what problems you're having with your code and would be much more specific and sound a lot less like a homework dump or work order.

Comment: I really didn't know how to say that my bad. I would post my whole code but its useless its just this part I don't get.

Comment: What im saying is how do I put two strings with the same variable together to make them add on.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.StringBuilder` is well suited for this.  For example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Ch#:").append(accountNumber).append(" WDs(").append(numOfWithdraws).append(")");
sb.append(" Dep(").append(numOfDeposits).append(")").append(" PreBal:").append(moneyString(balance));

if (hasOverdraft()) {
    sb.append("\t").append("YrlyIntRate:").append(yearlyInterestRate);
    sb.append("\t").append(" NewBal:").append(moneyString(balance)).append(" (OD)");
} else if (balance < 100) {
    // Do something else.
}

return sb.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks is there another way I can do this. We haven't went over this in class and feel she would take off if we didn't cover it.